# WPF No events to children

Tags: wpf

In the WPF Code

```
<Button Click="onClick">
  <TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink >Click Me!</Hyperlink>
  </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

How do I stop the HyperLink from receiving mouse events?  I don't want it to highlight, change cursor or anything.

Thanks in advance!
James

Comment: If you don't want the text to receive mouse events, why use a Hyperlink? Any reason you can't just use a TextBlock and style it like a hyperlink (blue/underlined)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in the XAML but you can do it in code by setting an event handler for every mouse event you don't want processed and mark the event as already being handled which should stop it going any further.

```
private void OnClickHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true; 
}
```